# How to formalize part of a protocol in ProVerif?

Tags: symmetric, proverif

I'm trying to formalize the following protocol in $\mathsf{ProVerif}$, where $m$, $p$ are messages, $j$, $k$, $h$ are private keys, and $\{m\}_k$ is the ciphertext obtained by encrypting $m$ with $k$. Furthermore, $f$ and $g$ are functions whose result does not reveal any information about any of the two arguments.
I also want to prove that no adversary not knowing $j$, $k$ or $h$ is capable of determining either the value of $m$ or the value of $p$.

$A:\;\mathsf{Send}\;\{m\}_k\;\mathsf{to}\;B$

$A:\;\mathsf{Send}\;\{p\}_h\;\mathsf{to}\;C$

$B:\;\mathsf{Send}\;\{m\}_j\;\mathsf{to}\;C$

$C:\;\mathsf{Send}\;f(m, p)\;\mathsf{to}\;A$

$C:\;\mathsf{Send}\;g(m, p)\;\mathsf{to}\;B$

So far I've written the following code:

```
free c : channel.

(*Symmetric encryption*)
type key.

fun senc(bitstring, key): bitstring. (*Encryption*)

reduc forall m: bitstring , k: key; sdec(senc(m, k), k) = m. (*Decryption*)

free m, p : bitstring[private].
query attacker (m).
query attacker (p).

not attacker(new sk_J).
not attacker(new sk_K).
not attacker(new sk_H).


let processA(sk_K: key, sk_H: key) =
    out(c, senc(m, sk_K));
    out(c, senc(p, sk_H)).


let processB(sk_K: key, sk_J: key) =
    in(c, x:bitstring);
    let z = sdec(x, sk_K) in
    out(c, senc(z, sk_J)).

let processC(sk_J: key, sk_H: key) =
    in(c, x:bitstring);
    let z1 = sdec(x, sk_H) in
    in(c, y:bitstring);
    let z2 = sdec(y, sk_J) in
    0.


process
    new sk_J: key;
    new sk_K: key;
    new sk_H: key;
    (
        (!processA(sk_K, sk_H)) | 
        (!processB(sk_K, sk_J)) | 
        (!processC(sk_J, sk_H))
    )
```

This code successfully verifies the proof (I think) for the first 3 operations, my question now is how can I formalize the last 2 operations/functions in $\mathsf{ProVerif}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just specify the functions with

```
fun f(bitstring,bitstring): bitstring.
fun g(bitstring,bitstring): bitstring.
```

and then use them in `ProcessC` with

```
out (c,f(z2,z1));
```

and

```
out (c,g(z1,z2)).
```

respectively. Unless you specify any destructors for expressions using `f` or `g` using `reduc` then the model will not permit the adversary to learn anything about the inputs. If you also want to make the adversary unable to compute `f` and  `g` for values known to the adversary, you should declare the functions as `[private]`.